Get URL before it's redirecting to the new URL
I'm writing this script where I need to retrieve a URL from the browser.
The testcase is, I first login to the website and click a button, and after the button click, it'll automatically open up a new page. In this new page it's initially having a URL and instantly it's redirecting to a new URL. However, this process happens so fast. Therefore, I can's retrieve the firstly generated URL using following code,
driver.getCurrentUrl();

How can I slow down the redirecting process so I can retrieve the original URL?
I'm doing this because, validating the original URL is part of the test requirement.
Thanks in advance.

you might try using a webdriverwait with expected condition of urlToBe(the_url_it_should_be)... if it times out, then test fails... if it returns true, then pass.

some of this will depend on how the redirect happens.  Any action that causes a new navigation will run through the standard wait for a page to load.  (that behavior can be changed via PageLoadStrategy...)  If the redirection comes from the backend, I believe Selenium will still be waiting for a page to load until some response comes back to the browser and DOM is ready.  If on the other-hand this is a JS request, Selenium will not wait, but the browser's URL will not change either.  Can you include the markup and/or code that processes the click?  You might need to intercept the request.

I am assuming that the new URL is opening in the new Window
Try something like this Inject JavaScript to intercept and pause the redirection. You can execute JavaScript in your test to temporarily override the window.location behavior, then switch to the new window
NOTE:
Execute the Javascript before clicking the button
// Inject JavaScript to override window.location
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.location.replace = function(url) { setTimeout(() => { window.location.href = url; }, 5000); }");

The complete code goes something like this
// Inject JavaScript to delay the redirection
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
    "window.location.replace = function(url) { setTimeout(() => { window.location.href = url; }, 2000); }"
);

// Click the button that triggers the redirection
WebElement redirectButton = driver.findElement(By.id("redirect-button"));
redirectButton.click();

// Wait until the URL contains "code"
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains("code"));

// Capture the current URL once the condition is met
String currentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
System.out.println("Current URL containing 'code': " + currentUrl);

